# Saving a file with JS but with newlines

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is code at http://codepen.io/davidelrizzo/pen/cxsGb to save file with JS but when I type text in a few lines , they are not in the same format in saved files i.e.

```
first line
second line
```

is saved as

```
first linesecond line
```

So how to keep lines in saved text file  ? Also is better or nicer/cleaner way to do save  to file in some JS library ?

Comment: Windows uses '\r\n' as new line. Your code is probably just saving '\n'.

Comment: I tried in chrome and keeps the new lines. What browser do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var text = $("#textarea").val();
text = text.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n');
```

Windows uses `\r\n` (*CR+LF*) for a newline character, and in your text you have only `\n`.